# How to pick an enterprise VPN provider?

Tags: network, vpn, audit

We have always deployed our own VPN using an open source package, but as our company is growing we've become increasingly aware of the importance of scaling this solution, especially now we operate across multiple countries.

We're looking at an enterprise VPN provider to take away some of the scalability challenges and who can also act as an VPN advisor going forward.

Does anyone have information on what questions are important to ask when choosing an enterprise VPN provider?

Comment: Apparently recommendations are off-topic.  Maybe you could ask for a list of criteria for evaluating VPN providers.

Comment: No longer consider this a dupe, as it's asking about enterprise VPN providers and the other questions are about personal VPN providers.  I nominated it for reopening.

Comment: As there has been a growing interest in "VPN service providers" (i.e. hosts that let you connect via VPN to their server, in order to mask your identity and activity to some intermediaries/endpoints) vs a "VPN enterprise solution" which would be a VPN system hosted by you (open source or purchased) solely for securely connecting your office locations and remote workers together.  Can you clarify the question as to which you are interested in, or both?

Comment: Hi Jeff. We're looking specifically at an enterprise solution for accessing our internal systems, not for masking identity. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the following criteria:

1. Privacy - In which condition the VPN provider will give your credential and data to other legal institutions?
2. Security - Dose the VPN provider has any responsive penetration testing made by a 3rd party?
3. Uptime - Average uptime.
4. Back-up solution - What if the VPN provider is taken down ... how will you work in those condition? Do they have back-up equipment at another location?
5. What's the law and the general monitoring level in that specific country?
6. Price and solutions/penalties in case they can't provide the service.